# Main Javascript dont process in template loaded with directive in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get this javascript function:

```
$(".panel-header .panel-toggle").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("closed").parents(".panel:first").find(".panel-content").slideToggle();
});
```

To work on html I've loaded through a directive

```
.directive('ngaddslide', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {'val': '@'},
        templateUrl:'template/portlet.html',
    }
});
```

and then i compile it in my controler

```
var html = "<ngaddslide></ngaddslide>";
var target = $('#element');
target.append(html);
html = $compile($('#element'))($scope)
```

The problem is, even tho the javascript works well in the original DOM and the template loads in the page, the js does not apply for the new html.

Is there a way to make the javascript apply to the added html?

Thx